# Recommendations for Books on Systematic Phylogenetics

Tags: phylogenetics, book-recommendation, cladistics

I am a physics major and need to study systematic phylogenetics for a research project. Can someone please recommend at least one introductory and one advanced book, please?

Comment: What did you find when you searched online? Have you used Google Scholar or some other search engine like NCBI to look for review articles? What did you learn there, and where are the gaps in your understanding? As it stands, this question is opinion-based, which is off-topic on this site.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what aspects of systematics you're interested in. Like, are you wanting to construct a tree? Are you comparing characters across species? Something else?

Comment: About which aspects of phylogenetics I'm interested in, mainly comparing characters across species and the methods for constructing trees, but since my knowledge is limited to Hennig's articles and a few youtube videos of a PhD in evolution, anything works, really.

Comment: I've managed to pick three books: [Joseph Felsenstein] Inferring Phylogenies, [Baum, David A.; Smith, Stacey D.] Tree Thinking - An Introduction to Phylogenetic Biology, and [Funk, K.A.; Brooks, Daniel R.] Phylogenetic Systematics as the Basis of Comparative Biology

Comment: Those books are probably a great start. I'm sure they cover it, but if you're comparing characters you'll need to be aware of [phylogenetic comparative methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylogenetic_comparative_methods).